# Please help with my unconfirmed transaction (for two days already)

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

Could someone pleas help me with this trancaction,highly appreciated :).

[Link underneath](https://blockchain.info/address/3DZz2htLk8J4sHAC3DD9UCpSU256EY2D82)

Comment: By now there are waiting like 170k transactions: https://blockchain.info/en/unconfirmed-transactions

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you can do is either wait or fee bump the transaction by using the replace by fee functionality to increase the transaction fee.

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Fee_bumping

Unfortunately the bitcoin network in being spammed with transaction by crooks operating competing cryptocurrencies the mempool has a backlog at the moment

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I bought from a "bank", so i dont think i can fee bump.

Comment: "banks" have nothing to do with it, you can still send more to the transaction fee to speed it up